# Running 32-bit version of Mono Embedded

Tags: c++, mono, mono-embedding

When running a C# program using Mono and you want to use 32-bit version, you just use `mono --arch=32`, but how can you do it when using Embedded Mono? I couldn't find any dedicated function in official documentation, and

```
char* options[1];
options[0] = (char*)malloc(50 * sizeof(char));
strcpy(options[0], "--arch=32");
mono_jit_parse_options(1, (char**)options);
```

results in Mono shutting down with `Unsupported command line option: '--arch=32'`

Comment: Its embedded, what is the arch of the hosting app that you linked it to ;-)

Comment: @SushiHangover well, that's embarrasing.... thanks