# Embedding 32bit version of mono when running on 64bit Linux

Tags: c#, c++, linux, mono, mono-embedding

I'm currently porting a C# plugin from Windows to Linux. On Windows the plugin is loaded using a DllExport nuget package, on Linux I'm looking to use Mono embedding.

The program that will use my plugin only has 32bit builds, so I would need to embed the 32bit version of Mono regardless of the OS.

On 64bit Linux, the default install of Mono only provides x64 libs and does not appear to be multi-arch compatible.

Is there an intended way to embed 32bit Mono on a 64bit system?

Comment: Not solved this specifically but have you tried the --arch switch on the mono command to see if you can execute in 32 bit?

Comment: According to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47016012/running-32-bit-version-of-mono-embedded), the --arch command is not available when embedding, the issue is that on a 64bit system, mono does not provide 32bit libs to link/load and mono does not appear to have multiarch, preventing me from installing the 32bit version if the 64bit version is already installed.

Comment: Ah I see. So —arch only useful if executing mono directly. :-/ hummm